# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: F. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, json

Trying to create a web request and getting JSON error:

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ClrErrorException: JsonReaderException ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: F. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at COI_203_DPDShipmentIdAndLabel.COIDpdServices.CreatePickupParcelRequest(COIDpdParcelPickupRequest request) in C:\Users\Admin6b338e5138\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\203 - DPD Shipment id and label\COI_203_DPDShipmentIdAndLabel\COIDpdServices.cs:line 25
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.COIParcelPickupRequestService.`sendRequest() in xppSource://Source/COI\AxClass_COIParcelPickupRequestService.xpp:line 158
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.COIParcelPickupRequestService.sendRequest()
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.COIParcelPickupRequestService.`run() in xppSource://Source/COI\AxClass_COIParcelPickupRequestService.xpp:line 110
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.COIParcelPickupRequestService.run()
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.COIParcelPickupRequestService.`main(Args _args) in xppSource://Source/COI\AxClass_COIParcelPickupRequestService.xpp:line 127
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.COIParcelPickupRequestService.main(Args _args)
   at COIParcelPickupRequestService::Main(Object[] , Boolean& )
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeStaticCall(Type type, String MethodName, Object[] parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeStaticCall(Type type, String MethodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.SysClassRunnerHelper.`runMainMethod(SysClassRunnerState state) in xppSource://Source/ApplicationFoundation\AxClass_SysClassRunnerHelper.xpp:line 30
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.SysClassRunnerHelper.runMainMethod(SysClassRunnerState state)
   at Dynamics.AX.Application.Forms.SysClassRunner.FormControl.timerControl.elapsed() in xppSource://Source/ApplicationFoundation\AxForm_SysClassRunner.xpp:line 52
```

My C# class code:

```
public class COIDpdServices
{
    public static COIDpdResponse CreatePickupParcelRequest(COIDpdParcelPickupRequest request)
    {
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(request.Endpoint))
        {
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(ToDictionary(request))
        };

        var responseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
        responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseJson = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<COIDpdResponse>(responseJson);
    }
```

COIDpdParcelPickupRequest:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace COI_203_DPDShipmentIdAndLabel
{
    [DataContract]
    public class COIDpdParcelPickupRequest
    {
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "OrderNr")]
        public string OrderNr { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PayerId")]
        public int? PayerId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderContact")]
        public string SenderContact { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderName")]
        public string SenderName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderAddress")]
        public string SenderAddress { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderCity")]
        public string SenderCity { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderCountry")]
        public string SenderCountry { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderPostalCode")]
        public string SenderPostalCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderAddAddress")]
        public string SenderAddAddress { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderPhone")]
        public string SenderPhone { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SenderWorkUntil")]
        public string SenderWorkUntil { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PickupTime")]
        public string PickupTime { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Weight")]
        public decimal? Weight { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ParcelsCount")]
        public int? ParcelsCount { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PalletsCount")]
        public int? PalletsCount { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "NonStandard")]
        public string NonStandard { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can't understand what is wrong in my class? And can't find which parameters causing parsing error... Please help

Thanks

Comment: Check the actual response *before* deserializing. All you know at the moment is that it starts with `F` and is thus not JSON. It's likely the actual problem is buried in there somewhere, anything from `File not found` to `Firewall overloaded` to `Form data invalid` (the fact that you have a success error code is unfortunately not a guarantee that the output looks like you expect).

Comment: Replace the class  you posted in your question with COIDpdResponse. And show us  a json that you have from the request before deserialization.